# Laravel Lumen does not load AppServiceProvider.php

Tags: laravel, lumen

I added dd to the boot function into AppServiceProvider.php.
There I added:

```
public function boot()
{
    dd("123456");
}
```

But the application works without dumping the 123456. Looks like the file will be ignored.
How can I solve it?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `bootstrap/app.php` file, you will need to have a line similar to this.

```
$app->register(App\Providers\AppServiceProvider::class);
```